# MS-Access 2003 Report Page Grouping

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have a report that I am having trouble grouping for my output.

`"Sorting and Grouping"` parameters are set to `"Name" and "Ascending"`

```
Group Header :Yes
Group Footer :No
Group On :Each Value
Group Interval :1
Keep together :No
```

Report Set Up

```
Page Header
Images, Label, Date
Detail
TextBox: Name
TextBox: UserID
Four SubReports Linked to the Name TextBox
Page Footer: Pg Nbr
```

I want to group by `Name per page`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with any errors you get + the image of your report?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.  The report is grouping the information fine, I just cant fuigure out the page break piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a footer to the Group and ..

```
 Force New Page: After Section
```

Comment: Remou, This sounds like what I am looking for.  How do I accomplish it thoug?

Comment: In design view, choosing Group Footer in Sorting and Grouping, how you do this is slightly different for each version. Next, right click on the footer and select Properties, then set the Force New page property.

Comment: Remou, That was exactly what I was looking for. The double click of the group header then ForceNew option was simple and quick!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to `GROUP BY :NAME` and `SORT :ASCENDING` ? Assuming you have data returned by your query to populate the report.

According to this [Access 2003 MSDN article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/keep-a-group-of-records-together-on-a-report-page-HP005187363.aspx),

***To specify how a group prints on a page,***

You can control how the elements of a group are printed in a report by using the KeepTogether property in the Sorting And Grouping window. A group consists of a group header, nested groups (if any), detail records, and a group footer.

- Open the report in Design view.
- Click Sorting And Grouping Button image on the toolbar, or on the View menu, 
  click Sorting and Grouping to display the Sorting And Grouping window.
- In the Sorting And Grouping window, click the field or expression for the 
  group level that you want to keep together.

**Set the Keep Together property:**

- Select No to print without regard for where page breaks occur when a 
   group is printed across more than one page.
- Select **Whole Group to print an entire group on the same page.**
- Select With First Detail to print at least the group header through its 
   first detail record on the same page.
- On the Edit menu, click Select Report. On the View menu, click Properties. **Set the GrpKeepTogether property to Per Page.**

  ***Note   When you set the Keep Together property to Whole Group or With First Detail, the size of the group (or the portion of a group that includes the group header through the first detail record) determines how Access prints the report. If either the whole group or the header through the first detail record is too large to fit on the page currently being printed, Access advances to a new page and then begins printing the report.***

So it could be that you need to change `Keep together` property.

Comment: @DesertSpider have you tried `keep together` property as per the article. It says if you use `whole group`, it will print an entire group on the same page. Try following the steps.